# access event by Facebook API

Tags: java, javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get information about event, to which I am invited.
I created access token in Open Graph page with all available permission and I use it.

I can fetch one event, but I can't see another, which I care. I noticed that event is "invite only", but it's settings are beyond my control.

It doesn't show in my events/maybe (when I clicked "maybe"), and when I try to access it by ID (graph.facebook.com/id), I get error message "Unsupported get request.".

I tried:

- RestFB (Java) - this is my purpose
- PHP SDK
- JavaScript SDK

Can I do something more except using FQL?
I read about it and I want to use simple request to get event, as mentioned on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/.

I can attach code if if this helps.
Thank You very much to look at this.

**EDIT**:
Java code:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    String attending = facebookClient.fetchObject("{event-id}/attending", String.class);
    System.out.println("Attending: " + attending);
```

It works like a charm with one event, but fails (return empty array of data) on another event (I was invited to both).

JavaScript code:

```
FB.api(
   'https://graph.facebook.com/{event-id}',
   'get',
   null,
   function(response) {
     if (!response) {
       alert('Error occurred.');
     } else if (response.error) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
         'Error: ' + response.error.message;
     } else {
        alert('test');
        response['data'].forEach(function(entry) {
            alert(entry['object']['name']) ;
        });
     }
   }
);
```

Doesn't return error, but response['data'] array is empty, while in another case contains properly data.

**EDIT 2**:
Furthermore, I tried FQL with restFB. It similary doesn't work - following code returns only one event, such as http requests.

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    String query = "SELECT name, eid FROM event where eid = {event1-id} OR eid = {event2-id}";
    List<FqlUser> event = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, FqlUser.class);

    System.out.println("Events: " + event);
```

Comment: Please, always share you code. That tells us what you've tried so far. Besides, this place is full of Geeks (including me) and code helps us understand you problem better.

Comment: Just to be sure, the second event you want to receive via the API, are you invited to it (because it's "invite only")? Because if you're not you just don't have the permission to "see" it...

Comment: I wrote: "I was invited to both". And yes, I still AM invited to it. I can see it in normal way. The last conclusion is obvious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to works as expected now. I think that was a bug in facebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a FQL query for all events you gave a (non-declining) rsvp feedback for:

```
select eid, uid, rsvp_status from event_member where uid=me()
```

If you want to see the according event data, use this:

```
select eid, name, description, start_time, venue, location, creator, host from event where eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=me())
```

Please note what is written about permissions to the event table in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/#permissions

You should be able to request FQL via the JS SDK like this:

```
FB.api(
   'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' + encodeURIComponent("select eid, name, description, start_time, venue, location, creator, host from event where eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=me())"),
   'get',
   ...);
```

Comment: I know that I can do this. But I wrote in question: "except using FQL".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really see it... I updated my answer to show how to query FQL via the JS SDK

Comment: Did You test this code? I copied & pasted it and get error: "Error: (#601) Parser error: unexpected '+' at position 6.". When I changed + to white spaces, I get "Error: (#601) Parser error: unexpected end of query.". When I change query to "select eid, name, description, start_time, venue, location, creator, host from event where eid = "{event-id}"" (because I know ID as I mentioned), I get: "Error: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql".

Comment: It works if you paste it directly in the browser's address bar. To use it in JS you first need to encode the query. I updated my answer, sorry.

Comment: It works, but doesn't return one of my events - it returns array of my events, but last is the same as penultimate. When I try to access it by ending Your query by eid = '{event-id}' instead eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=me()), I get "Error: An access token is required to request this resource." :( I'm tired and bored of it...

Comment: I guess you authenticated your user before you try to access FB.api, right? Otherwise, please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#graphapi Did you try to use the Graph API Explorer? If not, try this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%2520eid%252C%2520name%252C%2520description%252C%2520start_time%252C%2520venue%252C%2520location%252C%2520creator%252C%2520host%2520from%2520event%2520where%2520eid%2520in%2520(select%2520eid%2520from%2520event_member%2520where%2520uid%253Dme())

Comment: Yes, sure. Otherwise I could not have access to the rest of my events. I authenticate by login window. As to the second link, I'm confused now. It returns some of my events, but not all. Looks like some kind of bug in Facebook.